# Boost Serialization - Exporting in multiple CPP files

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, macros

The last days I have been struggeling with a Boost Serialization problem:

I am trying to serialize and deserialize multiple **derived** classes in multiple files. In order to keep it generic I have created template functions like:

```
template<typename T>
void
Helper::SaveToFile(T* data, std::string file)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(file.c_str());
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << data;
}
```

For serialization of derived classes to work, I need to use the Boost macro `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT`. However, I cannot place this template method in a CPP file and with the macro in the header I get these annoying "`duplicate init_guid`" errors.

And even if I choose not to use a template method, I still get these errors due to the fact, that I have different serialize methods in different files and therefore exporting multiple times.

Does anyone have any tips on either howto make it work with template methods, or how to export classes in multiple CPP files?

I have already tried splitting `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` into `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY` and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT`, still leading to the same error. Also, I didnt really know where to put the `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT` macro when there is only a Header file for a specific class.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.

Splitting into `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY` and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT` is indeed the key to the solution.

As with all C++ symbols with external linkage, you

- can put *declarations* in some shared location (like the header file)
- must put *definitions* in a *single* translation unit, so that only one linker input contains a definition.

In this case, simply include `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT` in at most one (statically) linked translation unit (think: cpp file).

See for background:

- [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work/6264256#6264256)
- [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track! However, I still get "unregistered (derived) class" errors if I only put it in one CPP file.